# API gateway and batchGetItem from dynamodb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I want to implement batchGetItem on dynamodb using API gateway. The response size of batchGetItem is 16MB. I wanted to know how API gateway is going to handle the requests for which the response could not be received because the response size exceeded 16MB. Also the aws documentation of api gateway (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html) says that the max payload size supported is 10MB; is this for both request payload and response payload?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the 10 MB size applies to request and response payload. If your payloads are expected to be higher than 10 MB, then you can apply the payload compression.

> **minimumCompressionSize:-**
>
> A nullable integer that is used to enable
>   compression (with non-negative between 0 and 10485760 (10M) bytes,
>   inclusive) or disable compression (with a null value) on an API. When
>   compression is enabled, compression or decompression is not applied on
>   the payload if the payload size is smaller than this value. Setting it
>   to zero allows compression for any payload size.

[Payload compression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-gzip-compression-decompression.html)

[Enable payload compression using AWS Console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-enable-compression.html#api-gateway-enable-compression-console)